# Having trouble printing out concatenated data after using awk statement

Tags: bash, awk, output, sql

I'm using Amazon Linux, bash shell.  I have this statement, which extracts and prints the second row from a file with comma-delimited data ...

```
awk -F',' 'select * FROM {print $2}' myfile.csv
```

I would liek to print out something a little more elaborate, specifically, getting my printed column into an SQL statement, so I tried this

```
 awk -F',' 'select * FROM user where id = {print $2}' myfile.csv
```

but the above prints out nothing.  What am I doing wrong?  Hwo can I extract my ID within other text (whcih in this case happens to be an SQL statement)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to embed the SQL into the `print` statement, thusly:

```
awk -F, '{print "SELECT * from user where id = "$2";"}' /path/to/input.csv
```